# what's a good way to repartition using windows tools?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I recently acquired a new HD (with 3TB) to upgrade from my current 500GB HD.  I cloned onto the new HD using CloneZilla and now I'm trying to repartition the new HD, but every tool tells me when I try to resize the NTFS partition that holds my Win7 that there's no available space even though it also shows a 2.5TB unallocated block of memory.  Any ideas on what's happening?  Thanks in advance for any help.

The tools that I've tried are EaseUS and Partition Wizard and the Win7 Partition Tool.

EDIT: So I did some research on this whole GPT vs MBR thing and it seems to me that I should be able to at least expand my Win7 partition to the 2TB limit

Comment: Did you convert the new drive to GPT? Or was the old drive already GTP? Because if you cloned an MBR formatted drive then the max usable size is 2TB.

Comment: I'm not particularly knowledgable about those properties, could you elaborate on them and/or tell me how to find out?

Comment: There are two (major, PC) types of partition table.  MBR, which has been around for a long time and can only deal with disks of 2TB or less, and GPT, which is much newer but can handle much, much larger disks (and doesn't need any of that "extended partition" silliness to have more than four partitions).

Comment: @avorum You can also read more about [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) vs [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) on Wikipedia

Comment: Do you know how to determine which they are?

Comment: What Darael said. Add to that that MBR was more or less standard in the time of 500GB drives and that most software gets confused with an MBR and 3TB drives (Often claiming to have ~700GB space instead, which is about 3TB-2.19TB). YOu can see the current state via windows diskmanagement (right click on the disk).

Comment: When I try to use the Windows Disk Manager, the extend volume option is grayed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to convert to GPT for a disk you are booted from. In order to boot in legacy bios mode you will need a 2mb partition at the start of a GPT disk formatted as a BIOS partition for the boot loader to be installed to for linux, however for windows it is not supported at all. (This was included in MBR by default, but is not in GPT because you can make an EFI partition to support EFI boot instead). I'm not aware of a simple way to change a bootable device to/from GPT.

The other problem is that windows only supports booting from a GPT drive if you boot in EFI mode, so you will need to boot your windows install media in EFI mode so that it will support using GPT disks. Basically legacy booted windows setup supports MBR only for install and EFI boot windows setup supports GPT only.

tl;dr: reinstall is required.

Comment: If that is so, would it be possible to allocate an empty partition and then transfer the Win7 filesystem over?  I don't still have the install disk for my Win7 so I don't think I can just reinstall onto the new HD

Comment: You will need one to use EFI mode, as the installer installs a different boot loader in to the EFI partition that will chain load Windows. You could create the new install and leave space for a partition, then copy the partition's contents over from your old drive to the new partition.

If you have access to a windows disk you can create a bootable USB key; as for booting it in to EFI mode you would need to specify the EFI option; usually if you press the button to choose boot device on startup it will have something like 'UEFI: sandisk cruzer' and 'sandisk cruzer', just choose the uefi one.

Comment: How do I set up a new partition to use EFI?

Comment: All you have to do is boot the windows setup in EFI mode, and then it will install the EFI boot loader and use GPT for the partition table; It doesn't support anything else in the windows setup. So as I said, find your boot device selection menu (F8 on Asus motherboards, F12 on IBM servers, etc at the BIOS/EFI screen) and then choose the one that shows EFI:[device]. If you want to use a USB key it only needs to be in FAT32 or UDF mode, and then just copy the files on the windows CD over; it doesn't need any boot loader as such to be manually installed for EFI, just the EFI folder.

Answer (score 0):

A probably reason is that the oldl disk was formatted using the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) scheme. That one only supports for drives up to 2TB.

You can install of clone a MBR to a 3 TB drive, but then you are either limited to the first 2TB, or you get problems with software which wraps around. (It counts to 2TB, then starts again at zero).

If the drive has a MBR then you can convert it to [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) via drive management. (See picture below). However make a backup before you try that.

[image: Image of windows disk management]

[Edit], to start it, go to [start] and type `compmgmt.msc`, or go right click on the [My computer] icon on the desktop.

[image]

Comment: Where can I find the Computer Management program that you're using in the screenshot in Win7?

Comment: If the Convert to GPT option is grayed out does that mean that it's already a GPT disk?

Comment: This will never work if he is booting off of the 3TB disk.